# is there a privilege type which can be used only to read database structure in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, privileges

I have a project which uses MySQL as the database. I want share the structure of database (table structures, table names, etc.) with a friend. However I don't like to share the data stored in the database with him.

I want to know, if there is any privilege type which allows only to read the database structure. If so, I can create a new user with that privilege and give it to him.

Comment: Grant USAGE (no privileges) to newly created user. Create stored procedure which retrieves structural information using `root` account as DEFINER and SECURITY DEFINER option. Then the user can retrieve needed info, and only it, by calling this procedure.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in several ways, including this method is that you enter the xampp file, then the MySQL file, and then to the data file, in which you will find all your data bases, and you can also send a table from them only, not all the data

[image]

Comment: it is indeed another way to share the schema only. However this question is specific to privileges